# Link in TextView not Responding

Tags: android, textview

I'm parsing a bunch of data with JSON and putting it into a textview and I want to be able to detect links and go to those links when clicked. I have been able to detect the links using this code:

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumbnail"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:linksClickable="true">
</TextView>
```

Once you click the highlighted link it crashes the app giving me this error:

```
08-22 16:57:33.632  23350-23350/us.bisonsoftware.tab2 E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1402)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1389)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:323)
        at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:75)
        at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:217)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:9235)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8135)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1622)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2565)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2243)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2156)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1622)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2565)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2243)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8343)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4743)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4190)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4301)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4198)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4167)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4190)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your activity code

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, the error you are seeing might have something to do with the wrong context. Where you are setting the text of the `TextView`, make sure the `context` with which you are initializing the `TextView` is right. Eg:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(YourActivityName.this);
```

Again, make sure this context passed is of the activity. Just writing `this` might cause issue depending on where you are defining the TextView. Is you use `this` within `OnCreate` etc, then that context should be fine. If you are defining the TextView inside any runnable or `AsyncTask` etc, then this might cause the issue that you are facing.

Hope this helps you identify. For more exact answer, please post the relevant Java code where you are defining the TextView.

Answer (score -1):

you have one thing to correct in your code remove  "+" before id near your image thumb nail

```
<TextView
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgThumbnail"
android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
android:autoLink="all"
android:linksClickable="true">
```

you are saying it as link but you dont have any url you are hard coding value to text view 
in android: text